# Eclipse changes variable on its own during debugging

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I've come across what seems to be a bug in Eclipse Kepler while debugging. One of my variables is incrementing itself randomly with every step of the debugger, even through steps that do not change the variable at all. Screenshots included below:

[image]

The method `advanceLine()` increments `progress` by one

[image]

The very next step, `progress` increments twice, before it even reaches the increment

There is another thread that accesses `progress`, but it does not modify it. These random changes don't seem to affect my program at all, just the debug view. Also, for some reason, the shortcut to Step-Into (F5) doesn't work despite being already bound. Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. I figured it out. I removed the variable watch from the Expressions view and added it back in. Lo and behold, it displays normally and my code has not altered at all. I think it was just the view that was acting wonky because like @Vineet says, Eclipse does not modify values in your code unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

Variable *progress* is a class variable and if it is getting updated ambiguosly, it is possible that another thread is modifying your variable. Please make your variable local.
There is no way eclipse interferes your coding logic unless you explicitly right click on a variable and change its value.

Comment: I changed the variable to private and made get methods to access it, but it didn't change the problem. I solved it though: it ended up being as simple as clearing it/ adding it back in.